# Cannot resolve symbol 'getBitmap'

Tags: bitmap, graphics, imageview, drawable

Присутствует ImageView в котором содержиться изображение, мне необходимо получить Bitmap для дальнейшего сохранения на SD карту.

```
 MainImageViev = frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.MainImage);
 Bitmap bitmap = (BitmapDrawable) MainImageView.getDrawable().getBitmap();
```

При этом .getBitmap подсвечен красным и ошибка Cannot resolve symbol 'getBitmap'.

Библиотека android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable подключена.

Sync Project with Gradle files пробовал.

[image: Fail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот таким способом...

```
ImageforFractal = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FoFragment).getView().findViewById(R.id.MainImage);
ImageforFractal.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    ImageforFractal.buildDrawingCache();
    BitmapDrawable drawableforimage = (BitmapDrawable) ImageforFractal.getDrawable();
    Bitmap src = drawableforimage.getBitmap();
```